# How to show a Google Map via OpenLayers on tiki-wiki 12+

Tags: php, openlayers, gis, tiki-wiki

I was wondering how can I show a Google map (or ArcGIS Server map) via OpenLayers on a tiki-wiki page?

According to the tiki-wiki online documentation [here](https://doc.tiki.org/OpenLayers):

> In Tiki12, all Google Maps specific code was removed in favor of using
>   OpenLayers, so Google Maps is accessible via the OpenLayers Google
>   Layer and the Natural Access project added further new capabilities.

However, there is no code example whatsoever on the tiki-wiki website to show how to access google maps via openlayers.

The closest thing I can find is the Map Plugin. An example is as follows:

```
{MAP(scope="center" controls="controls, layers, search_location, levels, current_location, scale, streetview, navigation, coordinates, overview" center="1.7282503,41.2257581,0" popupstyle="bubble")}

{searchlayer geo_located="y" tracker_id="1" type="trackeritem"}

{MAP}
```

However, no where in the above code is the data source for the map plugin specified. It's as if the data-source cannot be changed (and likely fixed to open street map).

Can anyone please provide a minimum complete example/instruction for doing what the documentation claimed to do?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Go to Admin > Maps (tiki-admin.php?page=maps), enable "Experimental" preference filter above the Admin panels and add the layer to "Available tile layers on maps" field.